# R lattice package, margin for auto.key border

Tags: r, lattice

The border around the lengend( auto.key) is too tight on the bottom. How do I increase it?

```
library(lattice)
    arr<- array(replicate(10, rnorm(10)), dim =c(10,10,10) )
dotplot(arr, type = "b", horizontal = F, col = techColor
        , main =list( " Centrality", cex=1.5), xlab.top="",as.table=T,
        ylab =list( "Centralities", cex=1.3), 
        xlab = list("Proportion Cutpoints"), 
        scale=list(y=list(cex=1.2,  alternating =1), cex =1),
        auto.key=list(  points = F, border= "grey",
                          space = "top", lines = T, columns=4,height=10,
                          title = "Technologies"),
        par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col = techColor, lwd=2, lty=1:6 ),
                            layout.heights= list(xlab.key.padding = 1), 
                            layout.widths = list(key.ylab.padding = 1)),
        par.strip.text = list(cex=1.5))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps if you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, people would find it easier to answer.

Comment: You should add your data, whether the actual, representative, or fake, to make this a reproducible example. Without it, no one can see the plot you are referring to. Again, take a look at the link @Andrie posted.

Comment: What is `techColor`?

Comment: I generate data in this example